# Can't access disk drives

Tags: permissions

When I'm trying to access my hard drives it's showing me the following error message:

```
No object for D-Bus interface
```

and I can't access them.

Can anyone help me get to my drives? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: **14.04**  @PhilUK

Comment: Cool, this will help try and resolve the issue for you